# Semantic vs Pragmatic

Tags: semantics, pragmatics

I am revising for my NLP quiz and am getting confused at the difference between semantic and pragmatic. I studied that semantic is the study of words and their meaning in sentences while pragmatic takes context into consideration.

1) When is a sentence semantically **incorrect** ? What do I need to identify to distinguish between correct and incorrect ? Are there any examples ?

2) How do I identify sentences that are semantically correct but pragmatically incorrect ?

3) Is a syntactically correct sentence also always semantically correct ?

4) What are examples of semantically correct but pragmatically incorrect sentences ?

Comment: Not sure about 2 and 4, but Chomsky's famous "Colorless green ideas sleep furiously" is an example of a syntactically correct and semantically incorrect sentence.

Comment: It's not clear what "pragmatically incorrect" would mean. Do you mean for example calling your boss "jerk face", assuming you don't want to get fired?

Comment: Hi Kong. Welcome to SE Linguistics. What's "NLP"?

Comment: @Araucaria The acronym usually refers to *Natural Language Processing* and is roughly a synonym for "computational linguistics" (though often more "computational").